# How to add a third factor of production to a static CGE-Model in gEcon

Tags: general-equilibrium

I am currently using the tool gEcon trying to create static CGE-models. As a starting point I am using a sample model from the gEcon developers. I already implemented small changes and managed that I was able to find an equilibrium after loading the model into R.

The model which works is this (open in Notepad++) https://www.dropbox.com/s/ljcpaf557lotq54/Model_2factors.gcn?dl=0

You can check running it in R and finding an equilibrium. Just run the R-File after changing the filepaths for the gcn- and the two excell files.

R-File: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2cffc6zk1ry46am/R-file%20for%202%20factor%20model.R?dl=0

Table: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8x5ophhvi51tydp/2factor_table.csv?dl=0

Map: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y7so3zryz8b508z/2factor_map.csv?dl=0

From this point I am trying to add the third Factor 'R' into the model, with properties just as the other factors. I define everything analog to how the other factors were implemented, but I fail to find the equilibrium in R. (For trying out just change filepaths in the R-file)

gcn-file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/elkrbn5oy811khp/Model_3factors.gcn?dl=0

R-File: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x09eukjufh2lfey/R-file%20for%203%20factor%20model.R?dl=0

Table: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tpx6znhm9g22fhm/3factor_table.csv?dl=0

Map: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r6w8reii4c05vwt/3factor_map.csv?dl=0

I have tried many ways of defining the new factor (number of equations need to match number of variables) but failed to do so correctly. The error message popping up in R is somewhat misleading, as the cause is not that the initial values of the variables are too far of. There is just no other error message it this point. I even set them once one by one almost exactly onto their correct values.

Can somebody see what I am doing wrong with my new factor? Any suggestions what to try out? if you need further information, I am happy to tell you.

Greetings,
René